# How can I identify or find the origin of this mysterious process?

Tags: process, cpu-load

I have a strange process on Ubuntu 14.04 that fires up fairly frequently. It appears as a bash shell in `top`, I haven't actually located it in `ps xfa`.

When it runs, `top` says it's using 215% CPU and my load avg shoots up to 9.  There's nothing in the root crontab and I haven't been able to locate anything else.  Suggestions?

Found it is PS it has this

```
23266 ?   Sl   106:29 sh    -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://0x6BBF635F:3333 -u 47EaZKYrX8NBBCE4N1H5zhXn3FR3tFmGYSBQWPPt2Vg8GmCwiGuwKdMbXKHTCCKpAUjU9AJ6Se4PU7G7uDLDoE4h3dtjkck -p x -t 3
```

That doesn't help me much locate it, or stop it...

```
#*/30 * * * * /var/tmp/". "/c
```

was active in a user crontab, looks normal except for the `". "` any idea what that does?

Comment: I smell a cryptocurrency miner.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, but still can't locate whats starting it up

Comment: maybe I got it this time, found an unusual entry in a users crontab, weird part is that account is never actually used to login....

Comment: You've been hacked. Nuke it and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Well you're right it was hacked... I left an insecure account available.  On the plus side, it didn't have much in the way of permissions so I'm not going to reinstall everything.

the ". " essentially creates a hidden directory, which is inaccessible without using the quotes in the path name.  Having finally found the path and removed the dir with extreme prejudice, and secured the account with a /bin/false for the shell. I believe this one is fixed.

ME